# Listening to back button stops it from working

Tags: javascript, cordova

Im developing a Phonegap app and I want to listen for the back button event. I do:

```
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){

              console.log('in back button');              

        }, false);
```

This works but the back button is then disabled, it never does anything when I just listen for the event. I tried:

```
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){

            return true;

        }, false);
```

but with the same outcome. It goes in to the anonymous function but does not then continue with normal back button functionality. How do I get the back button to proceed as normal while listening for it?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a listener like this, you override the default action. You can use back the default action by removing it:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", goToX, false);

function goToX(){
//Do what you want
}

//to cancel the override
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", goToX, false);
```

You Can't remove a listener if the function is an anonymous function

You can also keep your listener and set the exit action manually

```
if(platform != 'iOS')
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backbuttonListener, false);

function backbuttonListener(){
    if(Container.currentPrint == Main){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else{
        Container.setContent(Main);
    }
}
```

Don't forget that in I-phone, you don't have physical back button, so remember to add a logic one if window.device.platform == "iOS"